# extract information from file to create table

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

```
Jan 29 12:28:17 torsmtp2 postfix/cleanup[16193]: 5513512078E: warning: header Subject: Well Systems - Project Updated (Published Number 561-639-2188) from unknown[10.40.6.11]; from=<Accounts@example.com> to=<bg2833@work.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<CORE1UI1>
```

I'm trying to extract the information and create a table that contain the following:

```
DATE                EMAIL                Published Number
Jan 29 12:28:17     bg2833@work.com      561-639-2188
```

is it possible to use awk or sed to accomplish this?

I was able to do the following so far

```
head -n 1 file | awk -F ',' 'BEGIN { print "-----------------------\nDate \tEmail\tPhone\n-----------------------"} { print $1;} END { print "-------------"; }'
```

output

```
-----------------------
Date    Email   Phone
-----------------------
Jan 29 12:28:17 torsmtp2 postfix/cleanup[16193]: 5513512078E: warning: header Subject:       American Ramp Systems - Study Updated (Published Number 888-649-2186) from     unknown[10.40.6.11]; from=<Accounts@telmetrics.com> to=<bg2833@att.com> proto=ESMTP helo=    <CORE1UI1>
-------------
```

still not sure how I can extract the date / Published number and email

thank you

Comment: I'm curious - what do you think `-F','` will do given your input file format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{date=$1" "$2" "$3; email=phone=$0; gsub(/.*to=<|>.*$/,"",email);
 gsub(/.*Published Number |).*/,"",phone); print date, email, phone}' file
Jan 29 12:28:17 bg2833@work.com 561-639-2188
```

add printing the header in a BEGIN section and use printf instead of print if you want something other than tab-separated values in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Other way using sed

```
sed -re 's/(.*[0-9]:[0-9]+)(.*)Published Number ([0-9-]+)(.*)to=<(\w+@\w+\.\w+)(.*)>/\1\t\5\t\3/' temp.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, this looks like a log file, I am assuming the format won't change between different records:

You can extract date using the following code:
`date=$(cat extract.txt | cut -d ' ' -f -3)`

You can extract to email using the following snippet (I know it is a bit complicated though):
`email=$(cat extract.txt | sed 's/.*\( to[^ ]*\).*/\1/g' | cut -d '<' -f2 | cut -d '>' -f1)`

And, the published number can be extracted as follows:
`number=$(cat extract.txt | sed 's/.*Published Number \([^)]*\).*/\1/g')`

I hope this helps.

**Update**:
Email can be much easily extracted using the following snippet:
`email=$(cat extract.txt | sed 's/.* to=<\([^>]*\).*/\1/g')`